# Include code in string definition?

Tags: string, powershell

I have a string

```
$string = "Active Directory"
```

and I want to make another string

```
Active_Directory_Results.txt
```

I would like to just do

```
$otherstring = "$string.Replace(" ","_")_Results.txt"
```

but that doesn't work out.  What would be the correct way to pull this off?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should **not** use invoke-expression for that. The original answer is good:

```
$otherstring = $string.Replace(" ","_") + "_Results.txt"
```

But really, you can just use a $(subexpression):

```
$otherstring = "$($string.Replace(" ","_"))_Results.txt"
```

The $() tells PowerShell to evaluate that BEFORE defining the string.

As an alternative, you can also use string formatting:

```
$otherstring = "{0}_Results.txt" -f $string.Replace(" ","_")
```

Proving once again that with scripting languages, there's always more than one right way ...

Answer (score 2):

I'm not on my windows machine right now, but how does `$otherstring = $string.Replace(" ","_") + "_Results.txt"` work?

Check the [invoke-expression](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347550.aspx) command. It allows you to execute code in a string.
Like:

```
PS> $command = '$otherstring = $string.Replace(" ","_") + "_Results.txt"'
PS> Invoke-Expression $command
```

Comment: Yes indeed but I don't want to use concatenation to do it.  Like, how do you execute code inside a string?

Comment: Invoke-Expression : You must provide a value expression on the right-hand side of the '+' operator.
At line:2 char:18
+ Invoke-Expression <<<<  $command
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Invoke-Expression], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpectedValueExpression,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeExpressionCommand

Comment: @MattUebel there was a syntax error in my example. It was missing the quotes around `_Results.txt`.